# First webSocket video stops when run second one on a page

Tags: javascript, websocket, angular, video-streaming

I have Angular 2 application where i have a component named `stream`. The view of my app:

[image]

The app begins with just one `stream` named `stream1`. There is a background video, which works with webSockets. Video streaming by mobile phone with [Android-eye](https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye). It's launching [Wifi camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=teaonly.droideye&hl=ru) app on mobile phones and streaming video.

The problem is when there is 1 stream on the screen (blue block) video works well in there. When i init 2nd stream (yellow block) video in stream1 (blue block) stopped with last frame and video in stream2 (yellow block) works well. I think the problem with my js code. There is the piece of code, when i init new stream and bind webSockets:

```js
if (!self.videoSockets[item.clientId]) {
 var url;
 if (item.clientId == 'board1') url = 'ws://192.168.100.47:8088';
 else url = 'ws://192.168.100.6:8088';
 var streamer = {};
 self.state[item.clientId] = 0;    // -1: error; 0: idle; 1: wainting; 2: palying
 self.player[item.clientId] = null;
 self.media[item.clientId] = null;
 streamer.onOpen = function(event) {
  console.log(self.player);
 };
 streamer.onMessage = function(evt) {
  if (self.state[item.clientId] != 2) self.state[item.clientId] = 2;
  var blob = evt.data;
  if (blob.slice !== undefined) {
   var media = new TeaMedia(blob, function() {
    self.player[item.clientId].playMedia(media);
   }.bind(this));
  }
 };
 streamer.onClose = function(event) {
  console.log('onClose', event);
 };
 streamer.onError = function(event) {
  console.log('onError', event);
 };

 self.videoSockets[item.clientId] = new WebSocket(url);
 self.videoSockets[item.clientId].onopen = streamer.onOpen;
 self.videoSockets[item.clientId].onmessage = streamer.onMessage;
 self.videoSockets[item.clientId].onclose = streamer.onClose;
 self.videoSockets[item.clientId].onerror = streamer.onError;
 self.player[item.clientId] = new Player(document.getElementById(item.clientId), 8000);

}
```

Why initializing of `stream2` kills something of `stream1` ?